Is there a way on flutter to use the gps coordinates offline?
I'm trying to look for an approach to use an app to mark a visit on plsces with low or non-internet, so I'm wondering about how to manage with my flutter app, capture, then send to my local_db.
I've been reading about GPS but I haven't managed to find a good way to make it on the offline app.
Is there a way?
If so, how?
Do I need any package from pub.dev?
Do I need special permissions?
